# Parameter not found for "SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER"

Tags: database, oracle, security

I am using 11g db server.

The "SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER" value is not taking from the configuration file it is taking the default value "ACCEPTED" instaead of "REQUIRED". After the changes done through net manager I have restarted the listener. Where do I need to make changes?

## Trace file

```
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163270 : naeeinit:entry
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163321 : nam_gbp:Reading parameter "SQLNET.FIPS_140" from parameter file
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163354 : nam_gbp:Parameter not found
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163383 : nam_gnsp:Reading parameter "SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER" from parameter file
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163416 : nam_gnsp:Parameter not found
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163444 : naequad:Using default value "ACCEPTED"
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163473 : nam_gic:entry
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163500 : nam_gic:Counting # of items in "SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER" parameter
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163533 : nam_gic:Parameter not found
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163559 : nam_gic:exit
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163587 : naesno:Using default value "all available algorithms"
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163617 : naeshow:entry
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163646 : naeshow:exit
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163672 : naeeinit:exit
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163700 : naecinit:entry
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163729 : nam_gnsp:Reading parameter "SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_SERVER" from parameter file
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163761 : nam_gnsp:Parameter not found
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163789 : naequad:Using default value "ACCEPTED"
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163817 : nam_gic:entry
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163844 : nam_gic:Counting # of items in "SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_SERVER" parameter
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163876 : nam_gic:Parameter not found
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163908 : nam_gic:exit
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163935 : naesno:Using default value "all available algorithms"
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163964 : naeshow:entry
2010-09-22 19:11:13.163992 : naeshow:exit
2010-09-22 19:11:13.164018 : naecinit:exit
2010-09-22 19:11:13.164046 : nadisc:entry
2010-09-22 19:11:13.164073 : nacomtm:entry
2010-09-22 19:11:13.164100 : nacompd:entryBlockquote
```

## sqlnet.ora

```
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_SERVER= (SHA1)

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (BEQ, TCPS, NTS)

SSL_VERSION = 3.0

SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER = required

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE

SQLNET.CRYPTO_SEED = 'hkjhkhkhksfdsafdsafhkhkhkhklh'

SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER= (AES256, AES192, AES128)

SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_SERVER = required
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the server is picking up the right sqlnet.ora?

The server first looks for sqlnet.ora in the location specified in environment variable $TNS_NAMES. If its not found, then in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin

Check on the server machine for these two locations.